# Blurred image instead of solid colours?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am using BufferedImage for my background but when I reproduce it with the following code to make it bigger why does my image code produce blurred edges instead of solid colours?

```
public final class State_Play extends State_Template {
    private BufferedImage background;
    private int[] pixelelements;
    private int width,height;

    State_Play(){
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        width=8; //Configuration.appwidth,
        height=6; //Configuration.appheight
        background=new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        pixelelements=((DataBufferInt) background.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        maketuringarray();
    }

    public void maketuringarray(){      
       int singlecolor=new Random().nextInt();
       pixelelements[new Random().nextInt(width*height)]=singlecolor | 0xFF000000;  
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
       maketuringarray(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, Configuration.appwidth, Configuration.appheight, null);  
    }
```

Instead of solid colours?

Comment: Please post a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Because that's what upscaling does??

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that the interpolation on your platform is by default set to cubic or bicubic. This will make upscaling blurry.

Explicitly set it to nearest neighbour, to get the "blocky pixel" effect you want (if I understand you correctly):

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, Configuration.appwidth, Configuration.appheight, null);  
}
```